# Get value of select, from a list of users

Tags: php, html, post

i have a table of users, where a user has a name, a surname, a right, and a "commit changes" button. This way, i want to assign rights to a person. Every column has the userID in it, and the whole thing is created from a database.

This is my dropdown to assign a right.

```
<form id="myForm" method="post" autocomplete="off">
            <select name="rightsDropdownOptions" method="post">
                <option value="admin">Admin</option>
                <option value="masterEditor">MasterEditor</option>
                <option value="modulEditor">ModulEditor</option>
                <option value="teacher">Lehrer</option>
                <option value="teacherAndEditor">Lehrer+Editor</option>
            </select>
        </form>
```

This is my php-code, which is executed by clicking the commitchangestorightsbutton

```
if ( isset($_POST['commitChangesOnRightsButton']) ){
    $user = $_POST['commitChangesOnRightsButton'];
    echo "<script>alert(".$user.");</script>";
    $var = $_POST['rightsDropdownOptions'];
    if($var == "1"){
        echo "<script>alert(".$var.");</script>";
    }
}
```

If i click the button now i get the following error:
Undefined index: rightsDropdownOptions in C:\xampp\htdocs\Iiigel\PHP\AdminGivePermission.php

I've been working on this for a while now, and i dont knwo how to solve this, id be glad if someone could help.

Comment: There is no button named `commitChangesOnRightsButton` in your form.

Comment: Not the issue, but how will `$var == "1"`, ever?

Comment: Damn, the mistake was in my head. Thank you for helping Dharman. I had the button in a different form

Answer (score 0):

As highlighted by @Dharman you are making mistake in your code firstly you have to define post parameter "commitChangesOnRightsButton" into your code like this:

```
<form id="myForm" method="post" autocomplete="off" action"">
<select name="rightsDropdownOptions" method="post">
    <option value="admin">Admin</option>
    <option value="masterEditor">MasterEditor</option>
    <option value="modulEditor">ModulEditor</option>
    <option value="teacher">Lehrer</option>
    <option value="teacherAndEditor">Lehrer+Editor</option>
</select>
<button type="submit" value="Assign" name="commitChangesOnRightsButton" />
</form>
```

Hope this will help!